# Springboot SessionListener functions (sessionCreated(), sessionDestroyed()) not called

Tags: java, spring-boot, session

I am currently working on a springboot project and I want to execute certain commands whenever a session is created / destroyed. The class `SessionListener` I created is shown below.

```java
package cn.mypackage.listener;

import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session Created ---- ");

        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
        System.out.println("Current Session: " + session.getId());

        ServletContext application = session.getServletContext();
        HashSet<HttpSession> sessions = (HashSet<HttpSession>) application.getAttribute("sessions");
        if (sessions == null) {
            sessions = new HashSet<HttpSession>();
            application.setAttribute("sessions", sessions);
        }
        sessions.add(session);
        System.out.println("Current available sessions: " + Integer.valueOf(sessions.size()).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) throws ClassCastException {
        System.out.println("Session Destroyed ---");

        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        System.out.println("deletedSessionId: " + session.getId());
        System.out.println(session.getCreationTime());
        System.out.println(session.getLastAccessedTime());

        ServletContext application = session.getServletContext();
        HashSet<HttpSession> sessions = (HashSet<HttpSession>) application.getAttribute("sessions");
        sessions.remove(session);
    }
}
```

I put this `SessionListener.java` in my `/src/main/java/cn/mypackage/listener/` folder, and my entrance file is in `/src/main/java/cn/mypackage/`.

However, whenever I opened up a new private browser window and try to access any url, the server side never outputted any information, and breakpoints in both of the functions are useless.

Comment: Btw I added ```@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = {"cn.mypackage.*"})``` in the starter application, but it still have no output in the server console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that all `@RequestMapping`s I try to access does not pass a parameter of `HttpSession`. Only when accessing a url with a `HttpSession` parameter, a session will be created (if not before).

Example:

```java
@Controller
public class APIController {
    // this will not generate a session if no session exists, therefore not calling the sessionCreated() function
    @RequestMapping("/test1")
    public @ResponseBody String test1() {
        return "test without session";
    }

    // this will generate a session if no session exists, therefore calling the sessionCreated() function
    @RequestMapping("/test2")
    public @ResponseBody String test2(HttpSession session) {
        return "test with session";
    }
}
```